# Umbraco Publish - Server Error in '/' Application. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: umbraco, publish

During the publishing of a new Umbraco site, this error shows up

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 0):

It was due to **folder or file permission,** my error was fixed by giving full permission to all the files and folders published.  (This is test scenario). For production, you need to find the exact files or folders that need full permission.